# Use jinja template in a json property name with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I don't find a way to do the following template:

```
- debug: 
msg: {"registries":{"{{docker_registry.url}}":{"username":"{{docker_registry.user}}","password":"{{docker_registry.password}}"}}}
```

Ansible detects automatically a json and does not inject the value of {{docker_registry.url}}:

> "msg": {
>           "registries": {
>               "{{docker_registry.url}}": {
>                   "password": "arGgyprRu8R3nu7JBIki", 
>                   "username": "autom"
>               }
>           }
>       }

Putting into quotes give a "not serializable" error. I add backslash, backslash are backslashed.

Any idea to template this or to ignore json serialization?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting it seems to work just fine:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    docker_registry:
      url: http://foo.com
      user: alice
      password: secret
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: '{"registries":{"{{docker_registry.url}}":{"username":"{{docker_registry.user}}", "password":"{{docker_registry.password}}"}}}'
```

This outputs:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "registries": {
            "http://foo.com": {
                "password": "secret",
                "username": "alice"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would probably quote it like this to make it more readable:

```
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {
            "registries": {
              "{{docker_registry.url}}": {
                "username": "{{docker_registry.user}}",
                "password": "{{docker_registry.password}}"
              }
            }
          }
```